# Meaning of ['_a-z0-9-\\+] Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I was looking at the Struts 2 RegEx for email validation and was unclear on a subset of it. The regex as stated in https://struts.apache.org/docs/email-validator.html is as follows:

```
\\b^['_a-z0-9-\\+](\\.['_a-z0-9-\\+])@[a-z0-9-](\\.[a-z0-9-])\\.([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|tel|travel|xxx)$\\b
```

My question is regarding the part `['_a-z0-9-\\\\+]`.

I know that `_a-z0-9` means either a letter from a-z, a number from 0-9, or an underscore. I am not sure what the single quotation mark before the underscore means, or what `-\\\\+` before the closing square bracket means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the `'`,`-`,`+` character match in your string.
['_a-z0-9-\\+] means one of character match of `'`, `a-z`, `0-9`,`-`, `+`.